# I have a problem about Backup and Sync in mac big sur?

Tags: big-sur

I got an error when i open Backup and Sync in macos big sur:
I've tried to uninstall it, reboot the computer, installed it again,but error again...
and I've tried to type the code(sudo chmod a+wx ~/Library/"Application Support"/Google) in terminal but still, error jumped

How can i solve it?

[image]

Comment: btw,備份與同步處理==Backup and Sync

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like google fixed the problem i tried back up and sync today and it's finally working so download it if you haven't already.

https://www.google.com/intl/en-GB_ALL/drive/download/backup-and-sync/

Answer (score 1):

The current Big Sur release is an early beta, you should report any errors you find directly to Apple.

Comment: @DennisChang You can't expect a beta version to run without problems (that's why you never should run it on your main system), also Apple most likely will just fix it with an upcoming beta version.

Comment: Or good fixes there app. It crashes on.y mojave often

Comment: This issue is with a compatibility issue between a custom bundled Python 2.7 which ships with Google Backup and Sync and Big Sur.  Users should report 3rd party app issues to the 3rd party app developers (in this case, Google), not Apple.